# Using GPU from a docker container?

Tags: cuda, docker

I'm searching for a way to use the GPU from inside a docker container.

The container will execute arbitrary code so i don't want to use the privileged mode.

Any tips?

From previous research i understood that `run -v` and/or LXC `cgroup` was the way to go but i'm not sure how to pull that off exactly

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792161/is-it-possible-to-expose-a-usb-device-to-a-lxc-docker-container which is similar to your need.

Comment: @NicolasGoy The link was good but not that useful since i can't use privileged for security reason. The lxc-cgroups was a good pointer, but not enough. I found a way, and i will self answer when everything will be polished.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Writing an updated answer since most of the already present answers are obsolete as of now.

Versions earlier than `Docker 19.03` used to require `nvidia-docker2` and the `--runtime=nvidia` flag.

Since **`Docker 19.03`**, you need to install `nvidia-container-toolkit` package and then use the `--gpus all` flag.

So, here are the basics,

**Package Installation**

Install the `nvidia-container-toolkit` package as per [official documentation at Github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).

For Redhat based OSes, execute the following set of commands:

```
$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-docker.repo

$ sudo yum install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

For Debian based OSes, execute the following set of commands:

```
# Add the package repositories
$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

**Running the docker with GPU support**

```
docker run --name my_all_gpu_container --gpus all -t nvidia/cuda
```

Please note, the flag `--gpus all` is used to assign all available gpus to the docker container.

To assign specific gpu to the docker container (in case of multiple GPUs available in your machine)

```
docker run --name my_first_gpu_container --gpus device=0 nvidia/cuda
```

Or

```
docker run --name my_first_gpu_container --gpus '"device=0"' nvidia/cuda
```

Comment: As of 2019 this is the right way of using GPU from within docker containers.

Comment: Has anyone ever tried this from inside a Batch job on AWS?

Comment: I believe this is most relevant. Wish I had found it sooner, though I had to adapt the instructions from https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker to work with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @TimurBakeyev yet we still can't run ubuntu container on windows host machine?

Comment: @TimurBakeyev, could u help with similar question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600436/nvidia-driver-support-on-ubuntu-in-docker-from-host-windows-found-no-nvidia-d

Comment: The official NVIDIA instructions https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker say to install nvidia-docker2. Should they be updated?

Comment: Yeah, @WurmD is right. Thanks a lot for your guide Rohit, but please explain the discrepancy in package installation between your answer (`nvidia-container-toolkit`) and the [**official documentation**](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker) (`nvidia-docker2`).

Comment: @Atralb I can explain it after some investigations: In the commit 88a2fd contributer dualvtable moved the installation guide to the wiki, but the original Readme text includes the container-toolkit. I already created an Issue:https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1474

Comment: Docker fails to share GPU with `--gpus all` if it is not NVIDIA.

Comment: If `sudo systemctl restart docker` fails, try `sudo service docker restart`.

Comment: official documentation tells before restarting docker : Configure the Docker daemon to recognize the NVIDIA Container Runtime:  `nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=docker`

Comment: Is there any possible way to NOT use ```--gpus all``` to specify this but set some ENV variable in the dockerfile ? I a use case where it's hard to pass docker arguments.

Answer (score 139):

Regan's answer is great, but it's a bit out of date, since the correct way to do this is avoid the lxc execution context as Docker has [dropped LXC](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/docker_0_9) as the default execution context as of docker 0.9.

Instead it's better to tell docker about the nvidia devices via the --device flag, and just use the native execution context rather than lxc.

## Environment

These instructions were tested on the following environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- CUDA 6.5
- AWS GPU instance.

## Install nvidia driver and cuda on your host

See [CUDA 6.5 on AWS GPU Instance Running Ubuntu 14.04](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/cuda-6-dot-5-on-aws-gpu-instance-running-ubuntu-14-dot-04/) to get your host machine setup.

## Install Docker

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
$ sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

## Find your nvidia devices

```
ls -la /dev | grep nvidia

crw-rw-rw-  1 root root    195,   0 Oct 25 19:37 nvidia0 
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root    195, 255 Oct 25 19:37 nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root    251,   0 Oct 25 19:37 nvidia-uvm
```

## Run Docker container with nvidia driver pre-installed

I've created a [docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tleyden5iwx/ubuntu-cuda/) that has the cuda drivers pre-installed.  The [dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tleyden5iwx/ubuntu-cuda/dockerfile/) is available on dockerhub if you want to know how this image was built.

You'll want to customize this command to match your nvidia devices.  Here's what worked for me:

```
 $ sudo docker run -ti --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia-uvm:/dev/nvidia-uvm tleyden5iwx/ubuntu-cuda /bin/bash
```

## Verify CUDA is correctly installed

This should be run from inside the docker container you just launched.

Install CUDA samples:

```
$ cd /opt/nvidia_installers
$ ./cuda-samples-linux-6.5.14-18745345.run -noprompt -cudaprefix=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/
```

Build deviceQuery sample:

```
$ cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
$ make
$ ./deviceQuery
```

If everything worked, you should see the following output:

```
deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 6.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 6.5, NumDevs =    1, Device0 = GRID K520
Result = PASS
```

Comment: Why do you install lxc-docker if you don't need lxc then?

Comment: I agree it's confusing.  According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit) the recommended way to install the latest version of Docker is to install lxc-docker.  But there is no need to pass `-e lxc` when starting Docker, so it's using the default (libcontainer?).  Maybe they just haven't gotten around to renaming the package from lxc-docker to something else.

Comment: I have CUDA 5.5 on the host and CUDA 6.5 in a container created from your image. CUDA is working on the host, and I passed the devices to the container. The container sees the GPUs through `ls -la /dev | grep nvidia` but CUDA can't find any CUDA-capable device:

`./deviceQuery `
`./deviceQuery Starting...`
`CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)`
`cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38`
`-> no CUDA-capable device is detected`
`Result = FAIL`

Is it because of the mismatch of the CUDA libs on the host and in the container?

Comment: I don't know, you might want to ask on the nvidia forums.  Assuming the version mismatch is a problem, you could take this [Dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tleyden5iwx/ubuntu-cuda/dockerfile/) and edit it to have the CUDA 5.5 drivers, then rebuild a new docker image from it and use that.

Comment: when you passthrough the host GPU to the docker process, do you need another graphical card for your Host? I know you need 2 video cards to make VM passthrough work, one for host, one for VM. Is it true for docker as well?

Comment: @Xianlin sounds like you are misunderstanding docker containers.  With containers, the processes in a container run on _the same kernel_ as the host OS, and so they can access kernel modules / drivers exactly the same way as they would on the host, with no translation / passthrough middle layer required.

Comment: With nvidia-docker you can use NV_GPU variable to select GPU and it will add for you device arguments https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/GPU-isolation#nvidia-docker

Comment: Can you explain why image need to install nvidia driver? I thought only host installing nvidia driver (and use --device ...) is sufficient?

Comment: Currently there is no way of doing this if you have Windows as the host.

Comment: use [`nvidia-docker2`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/issues/168#issuecomment-625981223) maybe better

Comment: Please do not use this answer anymore as your solution.  It's completely out of date.

Answer (score 44):

Ok i finally managed to do it without using the --privileged mode.

I'm running on ubuntu server 14.04 and i'm using the latest cuda (6.0.37 for linux 13.04 64 bits).

---

## Preparation

Install nvidia driver and cuda on your host. (it can be a little tricky so i will suggest you follow this guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04)

**ATTENTION :** It's really important that you keep the files you used for the host cuda installation

---

## Get the Docker Daemon to run using lxc

We need to run docker daemon using lxc driver to be able to modify the configuration and give the container access to the device.

**One time utilization :**

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo docker -d -e lxc
```

**Permanent configuration**
Modify your docker configuration file located in /etc/default/docker
Change the line DOCKER_OPTS by adding '-e lxc'
Here is my line after modification

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -e lxc"
```

Then restart the daemon using

```
sudo service docker restart
```

**How to check if the daemon effectively use lxc driver ?**

```
docker info
```

The Execution Driver line should look like that :

```
Execution Driver: lxc-1.0.5
```

---

## Build your image with the NVIDIA and CUDA driver.

Here is a basic Dockerfile to build a CUDA compatible image.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Regan <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get --purge remove -y nvidia*

ADD ./Downloads/nvidia_installers /tmp/nvidia                             > Get the install files you used to install CUDA and the NVIDIA drivers on your host
RUN /tmp/nvidia/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.62.run -s -N --no-kernel-module   > Install the driver.
RUN rm -rf /tmp/selfgz7                                                   > For some reason the driver installer left temp files when used during a docker build (i don't have any explanation why) and the CUDA installer will fail if there still there so we delete them.
RUN /tmp/nvidia/cuda-linux64-rel-6.0.37-18176142.run -noprompt            > CUDA driver installer.
RUN /tmp/nvidia/cuda-samples-linux-6.0.37-18176142.run -noprompt -cudaprefix=/usr/local/cuda-6.0   > CUDA samples comment if you don't want them.
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64         > Add CUDA library into your PATH
RUN touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf                                     > Update the ld.so.conf.d directory
RUN rm -rf /temp/*  > Delete installer files.
```

---

## Run your image.

First you need to identify your the major number associated with your device.
Easiest way is to do the following command :

```
ls -la /dev | grep nvidia
```

If the result is blank, use launching one of the samples on the host should do the trick.
The result should look like that
[image]
As you can see there is a set of 2 numbers between the group and the date.
These 2 numbers are called major and minor numbers (wrote in that order) and design a device.
We will just use the major numbers for convenience.

Why do we activated lxc driver?
To use the lxc conf option that allow us to permit our container to access those devices.
The option is : (i recommend using * for the minor number cause it reduce the length of the run command)

> --lxc-conf='lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c [major number]:[minor number or *] rwm'

So if i want to launch a container (Supposing your image name is cuda).

```
docker run -ti --lxc-conf='lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 195:* rwm' --lxc-conf='lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 243:* rwm' cuda
```

Comment: Can you share the container?

Comment: Docker has a `--device` option to allow container to access host's device. However I tried to use `--device=/dev/nvidia0` to allow docker container to run cuda and failed.

Comment: I then succeeded with exposing all `/dev/nvidiao`, `/dev/nvidia1`, `/dev/nvidiactl` and `/dev/nvidia-uvm` with `--device`. Though don't know why.

Comment: The --device option wasn't implemented when I had to find this solution. You need at least nvidia0 or nvidia1 (graphic card) and nvidiactl (general nvidia device) and nvidia-uvm (United memory device).

Comment: Thanks for your hints on the `/dev/nvidia*` @Regan.

For @ChillarAnand I have made a [cuda-docker](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/shiquanwang/docker-cuda/)

Comment: I got it working with CUDA 6.5 too.  I wrote up a blog article: [Docker on AWS GPU Ubuntu 14.04 / CUDA 6.5](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/docker-on-aws-gpu-ubuntu-14-dot-04-slash-cuda-6-dot-5/) with the exact steps I followed.

Comment: Full instructions on using --device option in my answer below.

Comment: Might be an idea to point update this answer.  Its no longer recommended to do it this way

Answer (score 34):

We just released an experimental [GitHub repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) which should ease the process of using NVIDIA GPUs inside Docker containers.

Comment: Is there windows support?  It doesn't seem to be, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: There is no Windows support. Running CUDA container requires Nvidia drivers for Linux and access to Linux devices representing GPU, e.g. /dev/nvidia0. These devices and drivers are not available when Docker is installed on Windows and running inside VirtualBox virtual machine.

Comment: Still need the --device declarations in the run command? I've built a container FROM nvidia/cuda and the container runs fine, but the app (Wowza) isn't recognizing the GPUs while it does just fine when run directly on the host (this host, so I know drivers are fine). I'm running 361.28. The host is EC2 using the NVidia AMI on g2.8xlarge.

Comment: No everything is taken care of by nvidia-docker, you should be able to run nvidia-smi inside the container and see your devices

Answer (score 28):

Recent enhancements by NVIDIA have produced a much more robust way to do this.

Essentially they have found a way to avoid the need to install the CUDA/GPU driver inside the containers and have it match the host kernel module.

Instead, drivers are on the host and the containers don't need them.
It requires a modified docker-cli right now.

This is great, because now containers are much more portable.

[image]

A quick test on Ubuntu:

```
# Install nvidia-docker and nvidia-docker-plugin
wget -P /tmp https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/releases/download/v1.0.1/nvidia-docker_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb && rm /tmp/nvidia-docker*.deb

# Test nvidia-smi
nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

For more details see:
[GPU-Enabled Docker Container](http://www.nvidia.com/object/docker-container.html)
and: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker

Comment: This works well once you get all the steps. Nvidia doesn't provide it all in one place, but [this example](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2018/01/27/an-automatic-tensorflow-cuda-docker-jupyter-machine-on-google-cloud-platform/) gives everything you need to make it work with a common use case.

Comment: @KobeJohn - I just followed the installation instructions, the how to use command line and make sure my containers inherit from the cuda ones.  It just works for me.

Comment: Actually, can you give the real-life scenarios where use of nvidia-docker makes sense?

Comment: @Suncatcher - I'm using it in a cluster that requires access to the GPU for 3D rendering.  Dockerizing the apps made things simpler to deploy and maintain.

Answer (score 17):

### Updated for cuda-8.0 on ubuntu 16.04

- Install docker https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04
- Build the following image that includes the nvidia drivers and the cuda toolkit

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Jonathan Kosgei <jonathan@saharacluster.com>

# A docker container with the Nvidia kernel module and CUDA drivers installed

ENV CUDA_RUN https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/prod/local_installers/cuda_8.0.44_linux-run

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y \
  wget \
  module-init-tools \
  build-essential 

RUN cd /opt && \
  wget $CUDA_RUN && \
  chmod +x cuda_8.0.44_linux-run && \
  mkdir nvidia_installers && \
  ./cuda_8.0.44_linux-run -extract=`pwd`/nvidia_installers && \
  cd nvidia_installers && \
  ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.48.run -s -N --no-kernel-module

RUN cd /opt/nvidia_installers && \
  ./cuda-linux64-rel-8.0.44-21122537.run -noprompt

# Ensure the CUDA libs and binaries are in the correct environment variables
ENV LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin

RUN cd /opt/nvidia_installers &&\
    ./cuda-samples-linux-8.0.44-21122537.run -noprompt -cudaprefix=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 &&\
    cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery &&\ 
    make

WORKDIR /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
```

3. Run your container

`sudo docker run -ti --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia-uvm:/dev/nvidia-uvm <built-image> ./deviceQuery`

You should see output similar to:

`deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GRID K520
Result = PASS`

Comment: I get following output. cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL

Comment: Late reply, but it means you probably don't have a GPU on that machine

Comment: Would  a Cuda-9 version be nearly same as this?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik see this answer on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/967332/how-can-i-install-cuda-9-on-ubuntu-17-10, I'd say you could use this answer as a guide but I haven't worked with cuda 9 to confirm that the same steps would apply

Comment: Don't do it this way.   This is the old way.   Use the new way.  See link to my answer.  This method is fraught with problems.

Answer (score 15):

### Goal:

My goal was to make a CUDA enabled docker image without using nvidia/cuda as base image. Because I have some custom jupyter image, and I want to base from that.

### Prerequisite:

The host machine had **nvidia driver**, **CUDA toolkit**, and **nvidia-container-toolkit** already installed. Please refer to the official docs, and to [Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432877/2202107).

Test that nvidia driver and CUDA toolkit is installed correctly with: `nvidia-smi` on the host machine, which should display correct "Driver Version" and "CUDA Version" and shows GPUs info.

Test that nvidia-container-toolkit is installed correctly with: `docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:latest nvidia-smi`

### Dockerfile

I found what I assume to be the official Dockerfile for nvidia/cuda [here](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/master/dist/10.1/ubuntu18.04-x86_64/base/Dockerfile) I "flattened" it, appended the contents to my Dockerfile and tested it to be working nicely:

```
FROM sidazhou/scipy-notebook:latest
# FROM ubuntu:18.04 

###########################################################################
# See https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/master/dist/10.1/ubuntu18.04-x86_64/base/Dockerfile
# See https://sarus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/custom-cuda-images.html
###########################################################################
USER root

###########################################################################
# base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gnupg2 curl ca-certificates && \
    curl -fsSL https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list && \
    echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list && \
    apt-get purge --autoremove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV CUDA_VERSION 10.1.243
ENV CUDA_PKG_VERSION 10-1=$CUDA_VERSION-1

# For libraries in the cuda-compat-* package: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/eula/index.html#attachment-a
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-cudart-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-compat-10-1 \
    && ln -s cuda-10.1 /usr/local/cuda && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Required for nvidia-docker v1
RUN echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf && \
    echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf

ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64


###########################################################################
#runtime next
ENV NCCL_VERSION 2.7.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-libraries-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-npp-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    cuda-nvtx-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
    libcublas10=10.2.1.243-1 \
    libnccl2=$NCCL_VERSION-1+cuda10.1 \
    && apt-mark hold libnccl2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# apt from auto upgrading the cublas package. See https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/issues/88
RUN apt-mark hold libcublas10


###########################################################################
#cudnn7 (not cudnn8) next

ENV CUDNN_VERSION 7.6.5.32

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda10.1 \
    && apt-mark hold libcudnn7 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES all
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA "cuda>=10.1"


###########################################################################
#docker build -t sidazhou/scipy-notebook-gpu:latest .

#docker run -itd -gpus all\
#  -p 8888:8888 \
#  -p 6006:6006 \
#  --user root \
#  -e NB_UID=$(id -u) \
#  -e NB_GID=$(id -g) \
#  -e GRANT_SUDO=yes \
#  -v ~/workspace:/home/jovyan/work \
#  --name sidazhou-jupyter-gpu \
#  sidazhou/scipy-notebook-gpu:latest

#docker exec sidazhou-jupyter-gpu python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Comment: This answer really saved me! I had to install tensorflow-gpu on an existing docker image using ubuntu 16.04 plus a lot of other dependencies and this Dockerfile was the only way to install it cleanly. 
Note: I had to add a RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https after the first run (so that the later RUN can download from https nvidia urls) and I also removed the  apt-getpurge and rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ statements which were apparently causing some trouble.

Comment: Careful, you fail to reset the `USER` after installing CUDA. This can lead to issues with the image. Doing `USER $NB_UID` should reset it. Furthermore, I think this can be simplified by using `conda`, which is available inside the `scipy-notebook` image anyway.

Comment: Oh, and could you also post the Dockerfile source for `sidazhou/scipy-notebook`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's based from `jupyter/scipy-notebook` with some additional packages installed. I thought it is not relevant to this discussion tho.

Comment: @SidaZhou Ah, if it’s just like `jupyter/scipy-notebook` then that’s fine, yes. I haven’t gotten this working for myself but I haven’t worked on this project in over a month and I don’t remember whether I tried basing it off `scipy-notebook`.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried to run this, and I've received the following error. 

```python
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     cuda-cudart-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION     cuda-compat-10-1     && ln -s cuda-10.1 /usr/local/cuda &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```
I'm going to look at other alternatives for now, but may eventually come back to this if I find nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

To use GPU from docker container, instead of using native Docker, use Nvidia-docker. To install Nvidia docker use following commands

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey |  sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu16.04/amd64/nvidia-
docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd # Restart Docker Engine
sudo nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi # finally run nvidia-smi in the same container
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend installing CUDA/cuDNN on the host if you can use docker. Since at least CUDA 8 it has been possible to "stand on the shoulders of giants" and use `nvidia/cuda` base images maintained by NVIDIA in their [Docker Hub repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). Go for the newest and biggest one (with cuDNN if doing deep learning) if unsure which version to choose.

A starter CUDA container:

```
mkdir ~/cuda11
cd ~/cuda11

echo "FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04" > Dockerfile
echo "CMD [\"/bin/bash\"]" >> Dockerfile

docker build --tag mirekphd/cuda11 .

docker run --rm -it --gpus 1 mirekphd/cuda11 nvidia-smi
```

Sample output:

*(if `nvidia-smi` is not found in the container, do not try install it there - it was already installed on thehost with NVIDIA GPU driver and should be made available from the host to the container system if docker has access to the GPU(s))*:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   50C    P8    17W / 280W |    409MiB / 11177MiB |      7%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

*Prerequisites*

1. Appropriate NVIDIA driver with the latest CUDA version support to be installed first on the host (download it from [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and then `mv driver-file.run driver-file.sh && chmod +x driver-file.sh && ./driver-file.sh`). These are have been forward-compatible since CUDA 10.1.
2. GPU access enabled in `docker` by installing `sudo apt get update && sudo apt get install nvidia-container-toolkit`  (and then restarting docker daemon using `sudo systemctl restart docker`).

Answer (score 2):

Use [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) by mviereck:

https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker#hardware-acceleration says

> Hardware acceleration
>
> Hardware acceleration for OpenGL is possible with option -g, --gpu.
>
> This will work out of the box in most cases with open source drivers on host. Otherwise have a look at wiki: feature dependencies.
>       Closed source NVIDIA drivers need some setup and support less x11docker X server options.

This script is really convenient as it handles all the configuration and setup. Running a docker image on X with gpu is as simple as

```
x11docker --gpu imagename
```

Comment: This seems overkill depending on the needs.  The primary use of `x11docker` seems to be a GUI, with the option to enable GPU acceleration.