# How to build docker images on GPU

Tags: docker, gpu

We planning to shift the releases to docker; i.e. the software that we release will be based on docker. We also have an HPC cluster available.

I tried searching the internet but could not find a reference to make the docker build faster by utilising GPUs. If anyone is doing the same or aware of the procedure "How it can be achieved", kindly share the same.

**Edit** I am **not** talking about **accessing gpu** from inside the container, I want to use gpu while running **`docker build`**

**EDIT** I am not sure why the question is marked duplicate? Do we not understand the difference between `docker build` and `docker run`?  And how do we manage to give power to mark duplicate to people who dont even understand the topic?

Comment: How do you currently build your software on GPU's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GPU from a docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container)

Comment: @Sarvex is your CPU maxed out? I bet not, since creating images is IO intensive, not CPU intensive. If not, why do you think that using GPUs will help? You'll improve speed if you use a RAID array of SSDs. If you need to download images you may see that your *network* is the bottleneck. In this case download the images in advance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not about the speed of build. One usecase is that I want to compile a CUDA function which is needed in pytorch when building the docker.