# How do I pass data/info about the GPU (versions of OpenGL, OpenCL, mesa, etc...) from host to dockerimagr?

Tags: opengl, docker, gpu, vmware, x11-forwarding

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.2, fairly new install with just enough to start programming.  I do have a r9 390 AMD card which has been having lots of issues with the AMD drivers, but I don't think that is an issue.

I created a dockerfile with the following snippet:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
.....
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
WORKDIR /buildls
CMD ["bash"]
RUN apt-get install -y x11-apps
RUN apt-get install -y libcanberra-gtk*
RUN apt-get -y install libglfw3-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libglew-dev
RUN apt-get -y install mesa-utils
.......
```

After building it, I run it with:

```
docker run -it                       `#container process` \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix `#Allows the X11 server to be shared (GUI)` \
-v $(pwd)/volume:/app            `#Shares a folder, one down in current directory (~/volume) with ROOT/app in the container` \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY              `#Shares the display between the 2 systems` \
 opengl_why_you_no_work \
```

I created a simple GL loader program, with GLFW and GLEW, I made 2 versions to support OpenGL 2.1 (you'll see why later) and 3.2. Between the sample program that I wrote (with some debugging output calls) and

```
 glxinfo|grep OpenGL
```

I get some interesting questions.
Using the glxinfo call on my host, I get

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD HAWAII (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-58-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

On the docker image:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

hmmm, vendors? So, the program written for OpenGL 2.1, using:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2); 
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
```

Runs on both host and docker; simple rendering... but it works.  Even though it renders on the docker image, I still get this error:

```
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
```

If I try to run the version made for OpenGL 3.2 on the docker image, I get no rendering, no window, the same 2 errors above, and this output:

```
Renderer: (null)
OpenGL version supported (null)
```

instead of the 2.1 version on the docker image:

```
Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
OpenGL version supported 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

or the result of running either version on the host:

```
Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD HAWAII (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-58-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)
OpenGL version supported 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.6
```

So, I'm assuming it has something to do with the vendor, X.org versus VMware, Inc.  Can I override, passthrough, replace, or otherwise work around this? I could probably write the code for OpenGL 3.0 (where is the fun in that?) but the libGL errors have me concerned once I get more complex in the program.  Additionally, I want to try with OpenCL and I'm sure I'll have similar issues.

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer, however it might be some over kill... but it works!

I added to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-video-all
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libgl1-mesa-dri \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
....
RUN usermod -a -G video <username>
```

However, I think the mesa files were already there as a result of the

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

line.  I also added:

```
--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri
```

to the script to run the docker image.  Interesting to note, while I was troubleshooting, I upgrade MESA to the most recent version (17.1 here -> https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/mesa-17-1-ubuntu-ppa), now I have GL 4.5 on my host and 4.1 with MESA 12.0.6 on the image... Of course now I will have to workout how I will make it executable from a Windows/OS host.

I used the following references:

- [pg 303 of Robot Operating System (ROS): The Complete Reference, Volume 2](https://www.scribd.com/document/360234366/Robot-Operating-System-ROS-The-Complete-Reference-Volume-2)
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175164
- https://github.com/hilbert/hilbert-docker-images/issues/9
- [Using GPU from a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/809081/how-to-run-opencl-program-in-docker-container-with-amdgpu-pro

Comment: --device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri
 adding this fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, adding `--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri` fixed it for me as well

Comment: `--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri` was the real saviour for me