# Cuda Runtime/Driver incompatibility in docker container

Tags: docker, cuda, pytorch, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run this simple line of code in a docker container that comes with Pytorch.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.set_device(0)
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (35) : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:32
```

Running `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False`.

The host machine has the most up-to-date Nvidia drivers. Pytorch ships with Cuda, so there should be no incompatibility issues.

What could cause this problem?

**Edit:** 
@Patel Sunil's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container) answers my question, but I didn't come across this question in my search because their question is broad, while my question is specific to the cuda runtime/driver error. I posted this as a separate question for those who come across this error but don't know what it is a symptom of (namely, forgetting to use nvidia-docker).

Comment: I'm happy that you found a solution to your problem! But isn't this a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25185405/7968757)? Well, `nvidia-docker` is only the last answer. Probably mainly because the answer was written way after the question was asked.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the container with `docker`, not `nvidia-docker`. Running the docker container with `nvidia-docker` fixed the problem.