# Is there a way for GPU support without nvidia-docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, nvidia-docker

I am trying to get gpu support on my container
without the nvidia-docker

I know with the nvidia docker, I just have to use
--runtime=nvidia but my current circumstances does not allow using nvidia-docker

I tried installing the nvidia driver, cuda, cudnn on my container but it fails.

How can I use tensorflow gpu without nvidia docker on my container?

Comment: Because of the hardware requirements, this would likely require privileged containers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker)

Running a docker image on X with gpu is as simple as

```
x11docker --gpu imagename
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be happy to know that the latest Docker version now comes with support for nvidia GPU's. You'll need to use --device flag to specify your Nvidia driver. See - [How to use GPU a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container)

Earlier, you had to install nvidia-docker which was plain docker with a thin layer of abstraction for nvidia GPU's. See - [Nvidia Docker](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-docker-gpu-server-application-deployment-made-easy/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply install nvidia drivers in a docker container. The container must have access to the hardware. Though I'm not certain, but mounts might help you with that issue. See- https://docs.docker.com/storage/

You can **use anaconda** to install and use Tensorflow-gpu.

Make sure you have the latest nvidia drivers installed.
Install Anaconda 2 or 3 from the official site. 
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Create a new environment and install tensorflow-gpu and cudatoolkit.

`$conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu python cudnn cudatoolkit`

You can also specify the version of application.

E.g `$conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu python=3.5 cudnn cudatoolkit=8`

Please do check if your hardware has the minimum compute capability to support the version of CUDA that you are/will be using.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't pass `--runtime=nvidia` as a command-line option (eg `docker-compose`), you can set the default runtime in the Docker daemon config file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia"
}
```