# Pycharm debugging using docker with GPUs

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pycharm, nvidia

## The Goal:

To debug a Python application in PyCharm, where I set the interpreter to a custom docker image, using Tensorflow and so requiring a GPU. The problem is that PyCharm's *command-building* doesn't offer a way to discover available GPUs, as far as I can tell.

## Terminal - it works:

Enter a container with the following command, specifying which GPUs to make available (`--gpus`):

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus=all --entrypoint="/bin/bash" 3b6d609a5189        # image has an entrypoint, so I overwrite it
```

Inside the container, I can run `nvidia-smi` to see a GPU is found, and confirm Tensorflow finds it, using:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
# physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Quadro P2000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"]
```

If I don't use the `--gpus` flag, no GPUs are discovered, as expected.
Note: using docker version 19.03 and above, Nvidia runtimes are supports natively, so there is no need for `nvidia-docker` and also, the docker-run argument `--runtime=nvidia` is also deprecated. [Relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432877/3126298).

## PyCharm - it doesn't work

Here is the configuration for the run:

[image: configuration]

*(I realise some of those paths might look incorrect, but that isn't an issue for now)*

I set the interpreter to point to the same docker image and run the Python script, set a custom `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as an argument to the run that matches where the `libcuda.so` is `locate`d in the docker image (I found it interactively inside a running container), but still no device is found:

[image: error message]

The error message shows the the CUDA library was able to be loaded (i.e. is was found on that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), but the device was still not found. This is why I believe the docker run argument `--gpus=all` must be set somewhere. I can't find a way to do that in PyCharm.

## Other things I have tried:

1. In PyCharm, using a Docker execution template config (instead of a Python template) where it is possible to specify *run arguments*, so I hoped to pass `--gpus=all`, but that seems not to be supported by the parser of those options:

[image: parse error]

2. I tried to set the default runtime to be `nvidia` in the docker daemon by including the following config in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

> ```
> {
>     "runtimes": {
>         "nvidia": {
>             "runtimeArgs": ["gpus=all"]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I am not sure of the correct format for this, however. I have tried a few variants of the above, but nothing got the GPUs recognised. The example above could at least be parsed and allow me to restart the docker daemon without errors.

3. I noticed in the official Tensorflow docker images, they install a package (via `apt install`) called `nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1804-5.0.2-ga-cuda10.0`, which sounds like a great tool, albeit seemingly just for TensorRT. I added it to my Dockerfile as a shot in the dark, but unfortunately it did not fix the issue.
4. Adding `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all` etc. to the environment variables of the PyCharm configuration, with no luck.

I am using Python 3.6, PyCharm Professional 2019.3 and Docker 19.03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that **attempt 2.** in the "Other things I tried" section of my post was the right direction, and using the following allowed PyCharm's remote interpreter (the docker image) locate the GPU, as the Terminal was able to.

I added the following into `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

It is also necessary to restart the docker service after saving the file:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

*Note: that kills all running docker containers on the system*

Answer (score 5):

Docker GPUs' support is now available in PyCharm 2020.2 without global `default-runtime`.
Just set `--gpus all` under 'Docker container settings' section in the [configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vgb.png).

If `no NVIDIA GPU device is present: /dev/nvidia0 does not exist` error still occur, make sure to uncheck `Run with Python Console`, because it's still not working properly.

Comment: Ridiculous how this tiny thing `Run with Python Console` just simply breaks input parameters

Answer (score 1):

Check out Michał De's answer, it works. However, an interactive console is still broken. With some `docker inspect` I figured out that using the option `Run with Python Console` overwrites docker config ignoring provided options `--gpus all`. I couldn't stand such a loss in quality of life and forced pycharm to play nice using `docker-compose`.

Behold, the WORKAROUND.

---

**1. How to test GPU in Tensorflow**

```py
import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

should return something like

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

---

**2. Make sure you have a simple docker container that works**

```sh
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
docker run --gpus all -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

the last print should be as described in step 1. Otherwise see [nvidia guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#installation-guide) or [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker).

---

**3. Create a compose file and test it**

```yaml
version: '3'
# ^ fixes another pycharm bug
services:
  test:
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter  
    # ^ or your own
    command: python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"  
    # ^ irrelevant, will be overwridden by pycharm, but usefull for testing
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: all
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

```sh
docker-compose --file your_compose_file up
```

Again, you should see the same output as described in the step 1. Given that step 2 was successful this should go without surprises.

---

**4. Set up this compose as an interpreter in pycharm**

- Configuration files: your_compose_file
- Service: test (it just works, but you can have more [fun](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#run) )

[image]

---

**5. Enjoy your interactive console while running a GPU enabled docker.**