# Using GPU inside docker container - CUDA Version: N/A and torch.cuda.is_available returns False

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pytorch, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to use GPU from inside my docker container. I'm using docker with version 19.03 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Outside the docker container if I run `nvidia-smi` I get the below output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I run the same thing inside the container created from `nvidia/cuda` docker image, I get the same output as above and everything is running smoothly. `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`.

But if I run the same `nvidia-smi` command inside any other docker container, it gives the following output where you can see that the CUDA Version is coming as **N/A**. Inside the containers `torch.cuda.is_available()` also returns `False`.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: N/A      |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have installed `nvidia-container-toolkit` using the following commands.

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

I started my containers using the following commands

```
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
sudo docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
```

Comment: This isn't a CUDA programming  related question and shouldn't be tagged as such

Comment: @talonmies, May I know why this isn't related to CUDA? I'm trying to use CUDA framework from Docker to leverage the GPU connected to the host right? Am I incorrect in saying that?

Comment: Facing the same situation. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @arun I just changed the docker base image to nvidia/cuda image to get it working

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using nvidia/cuda as base image..

Comment: @SidaZhou, Please update here if you find any solution. I'd like to use it too. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I missed `--gpus all`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi` should NOT return `CUDA Version: N/A` if everything (aka nvidia driver, CUDA toolkit, and nvidia-container-toolkit) is installed correctly on the host machine.

Given that `docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi` returns correctly. I also had problem with `CUDA Version: N/A` inside of the container, which I had luck in solving:

Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64422438/2202107 (obviously you need to adjust and install the matching/correct versions of everything)

Comment: Once `CUDA Version: N/A` problem was solved, tensorflow (gpu) just worked immediately without any configuration. I assume pytorch will do the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and seems like it would work for me as well. I've gone through your answer and saw that there are various other packages which needs to be installed. For me, I'm currently deploying a package on a server which is not connected to the internet. So, I'll have to manually download the packages mentioned and their dependencies. I'll try to see if I could do it in the future.

Comment: @SaiChander I have the same limitation, that's why I use docker. I can install everything inside docker on my local machine (where internet isn't restricted) and then upload the image to the server (where internet is restricted) either via internal docker registeries or via docker load/save

Comment: I create a docker image and then use docker save to create a tar file and move the tar file to the server where internet is not accessible, I use docker load command to load the image from the tar file. Now, When I run the docker run command, it will still try to execute the apt-get update && apt-get isntall...  command right? Or can I somehow avoid it?

Comment: You need to install nvidia-container-toolkit https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html

Answer (score 9):

For anybody arriving here looking how to do it with **docker compose**, add to your service:

```yaml
deploy:
  resources:
    reservations:
      devices:
      - driver: nvidia
        capabilities:
          - gpu
          - utility # nvidia-smi
          - compute # CUDA
          - video   # NVDEC/NVENC/NVCUVID. For instance to use a hardware accelerated ffmpeg. Skip it if you don't need it
```

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support

You can find a list of the driver capabilities here: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/docker-specialized.html#driver-capabilities

Comment: Works for me! 

My image uses nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-devel-ubuntu20.04, and when I check with nvidia-smi and nvcc --version, they run but my torch could not detect the CUDA installation. But after using these configurations, torch.cuda.is_available() finally returns True.