# Inside the Docker container, how to check the GPU graphics card information and usage of the server?

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia

Now there is an application in the ubuntu container. At this time, it is necessary to check the GPU resources of the host outside the container. How should it be implemented in the docker container?

In other words, I hope to monitor the gpu resources of the host outside the container inside the container. Finally, refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751883/using-gpu-inside-docker-container-cuda-version-n-a-and-torch-cuda-is-availabl), modify the base image to `nvidia/cuda`, and finally modify the deployment to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to access a hardware device with a Docker image under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274927/is-it-possible-to-access-a-hardware-device-with-a-docker-image-under-windows)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751883/using-gpu-inside-docker-container-cuda-version-n-a-and-torch-cuda-is-availabl

Comment: @NicoHaase 
The question of this link did not seem to be able to solve it well. I hope to view the GPU graphics card in the current Ubuntu container for subsequent use.  But now the graphics device on the host cannot be monitored.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: A Docker container by design is in an isolated environment, and it can't necessarily see host resource utilization or hardware devices.  If this isn't a duplicate of one of the questions already mentioned, what are you trying to access, what code have you written so far, and what problems are you running into?

Comment: @NicoHaase The last link helped, thanks.

Comment: @DavidMaze The question was solved for the time being.