# Using windows host GPU in a docker container

Tags: docker, nvidia

I am trying to access my host GPUs in a docker container.
However, while running a basic check to see if docker container can access the GPU, it keeps failing with the below error:

### Dockerfile

```
# FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubi7

CMD ["nvidia-smi"]

# docker build -f Dockerfile_NVIDIA --tag nvidia-test .
# docker run --gpus=all nvidia-test
# docker run --gpus all nvidia-test
```

### Error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request: unknown.
```

I tried referring to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container) but of no help.