# CUDA to docker-container

Tags: python, docker, deployment, dockerfile

I need to make docker of my server, but it works only with cuda, how can i add it in my Dockerfile?

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000

RUN sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure # Here

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

I try to do it bellow, but it doesn't work, please, help

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with a [CUDA docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda) and then install python, for example

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.1.1-runtime-ubuntu20.04 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container
Running the docker with GPU support:
docker run --name my_all_gpu_container --gpus all -t nvidia/cuda
Please note, the flag --gpus all is used to assign all available gpus to the docker container.
To assign specific gpu to the docker container (in case of multiple GPUs available in your machine):
docker run --name my_first_gpu_container --gpus device=0 nvidia/cuda
Or:
docker run --name my_first_gpu_container --gpus '"device=0"' nvidia/cuda